# Convert wide format to long format for n pairs of start and end dates

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a table with 51 columns, id and 50 pairs of start dates and end dates in a wide format.  I would like to convert this to a long format with start and end dates.  Sample code given below for only 2 pairs of start and end dates. Also new rows have to be inserted between the end of 'end' and beginning of 'start'. Besides, each id should have two extra rows from 'pre' to the first start date and another, from the last end date to 'post' for each id. Also note that end2 could be same as post.

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- fread("
id  pre               post       start1     end1       start2        end2        var1
A   01/01/1992   12/31/1992   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  03/25/1992  03/30/1992       1
C   04/01/1992   06/30/1992   05/28/1992  06/30/1992   NA          NA              5
D   05/01/1992   06/01/1992     NA           NA         NA         NA  NA
E   07/18/1992   08/02/1992     07/15/1992  07/22/1992  NA         NA   1
F   06/02/1992   09/03/1992   07/15/1992   07/17/1992  07/20/1992 09/10/1992      2" )

cols <- c("pre","post","start1", "end1","start2", "end2")
table1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols=cols]


Final table should be-
id  start         end       var1
A   01/01/1992   03/14/1992  -99
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992   1
A   03/21/1992  03/24/1992  -99
A   03/25/1992  03/30/1992   1
A   04/01/1992  12/31/1992   -99
C   04/01/1992  05/27/1992   -99
C   05/28/1992  06/30/1992   5
D   05/01/1992   06/01/1992  NA
E   07/18/1992   07/22/1992  NA
E   07/23/1992   08/02/1992  1 
F   06/02/1992   07/14/1992  2
F   07/15/1992   07/17/1992  2
F  07/18/1992    07/19/1992  2
F  07/20/1992    09/03/1992  2
```

**Correction to my original post**:  I found out that in my data, pre and post dates may not appear before and after start1 and end2 respectively for some IDs. I have added 3 extra IDs above for examples. That is pre date could be between start1 and end1 or end1 and start1.  Likewise the post date could lie anywhere on the time line but will come after pre. The final data should start with *pre* and end with *post* retaining the start and end ranges for all rows except in some cases for first and last rows of some IDs.

Comment: I struggle to understand how to get from `table1` to your final table. You mention multiple pairs of `start` & `end` date columns. But your sample data also has a `pre` and `post` column that somehow gets integrated into your final table. How? Why are the dates of your first row of your final table `01/01/1992` (which is `pre` for `id=A`) and `03/14/1992` (which has no matching entry in `table1`)? Why are some `var1` values `-99`. Some `var1` values seem to get repeated (`var1 = 1` for `id=A` shows up twice), others don't (`var1 = 5` for `id=B` appears only once). What are the rules here?

Comment: pre and post are the end points of the entire range of dates for each ID. You can think of as a sequence, pre < start1 <end1 < start2 < end2 <....<post.  Each pair of start and end dates gets a row, (start1,end1),(start2,end2)....(start50,end50).  Further rows that are inserted-(pre,start1-1),(end1+1,start2-1)... (end50+1,post) get missing var1.  We should have rows with no gaps in dates, starting with pre and with breaks at end1-1, end1,end2....end50 ending at post.  Thanks for asking Maurits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option assuming that pre and post cover the entire range:

```
setnames(table1, c("pre", "post"), c("start0", "end0"))
mDT <- melt(table1, id.vars=c("id", "var1"), measure.vars=patterns("start","end"), 
    na.rm=TRUE, value.name=c("start","end"))

ans <- mDT[, {
        b <- c(start, end[.N] + 1L)
        e <- c(start[2L] - 1L, end[-1L], end[1L])
        .(start=c(b, e[-.N]+1L), end=c(e, b[-1L]-1L))
    }, id][start <= end]
setkey(ans, id, start, end)
ans[, var1 := -99L][mDT, on=.(id, start, end), var1 := i.var1]
```

---

edit: For the new data there are some inconsistencies in whether the pre-post period should also have the same var1 when pre-post does not cover the ranges in start1 to endN. However, if we assume that pre-post should not have the var1 value, then here is an option for the case where pre-post does not cover all start and end dates:

```
setnames(table1, c("pre", "post"), c("start0", "end0"))
mDT <- melt(table1, id.vars=c("id", "var1"), measure.vars=patterns("start","end"),
    value.name=c("start_d","end_d"), na.rm=TRUE)

#identify the pre-post range
mDT[, ri := rowid(id, var1)]

#as per before, we create continuous intervals out of these start and end dates
ans <- mDT[order(id, start_d, end_d), {
    if (.N > 1L) {
        ms <- start_d[1L]
        me <- end_d[1L]
        dates <- c(start_d, end_d+1L)
        sdates <- sort(dates[ms <= dates & dates < me])
        .(start_d=sdates, end_d=c(sdates[-1L]-1L, me))
    } else
        .(start_d, end_d)
}, .(id, var1)][start_d <= end_d]
setkey(ans, id, start_d, end_d)

#identify which ranges falls within the non pre-post periods
w <- unique(ans[mDT[ri!=1L], on=.(id, start_d>=start_d, end_d<=end_d),
    mult="last", nomatch=0L, which=TRUE])
ans[!w, var1 := -99L]
```

output:

```
    id var1    start_d      end_d
 1:  A  -99 1992-01-01 1992-03-14
 2:  A    1 1992-03-15 1992-03-20
 3:  A  -99 1992-03-21 1992-03-24
 4:  A    1 1992-03-25 1992-03-30
 5:  A  -99 1992-03-31 1992-12-31
 6:  C  -99 1992-04-01 1992-05-27
 7:  C    5 1992-05-28 1992-06-30
 8:  D  -99 1992-05-01 1992-06-01
 9:  E  -99 1992-07-15 1992-07-17
10:  E    1 1992-07-18 1992-07-22
11:  F  -99 1992-06-02 1992-07-14
12:  F    2 1992-07-15 1992-07-17
13:  F  -99 1992-07-18 1992-07-19
14:  F    2 1992-07-20 1992-09-03
```

Comment: Wow! Chinsoon.  Such a compact code and works so beautifully.  Thank you so much.  I am having difficulty understanding the following code.  Sorry I am not an expert in R as you are.  Hope it is not too much trouble for you to briefly explain how the code works.  If you are not able to then not to worry.   Thanks again Chinsoon!.  ans <- mDT[, {
        b <- c(start, end[.N] + 1L)
        e <- c(start[2L] - 1L, end[-1L], end[1L])
        .(start=c(b, e[-.N]+1L), end=c(e, b[-1L]-1L))
    }, id][start <= end]

Comment: Easier if I work out by hand and post a pic. Ok if u wait for a couple of days?

Comment: Absolutely! I will wait for your explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: I have added a correction to my original post.  Some data issues that I found out later.  When you get time, could you be able to make changes to your answer?  Thanks as always.

Comment: @Pam there are some inconsistencies in whether var1 is the value for pre-post range as well. I have added an approach assuming that var1 should not be used for ranges outside of start and end. A good example is id=D

Comment: Thanks for the code and taking the time to write it.  The end_d for ID E on rows 9,10,11 of your output have the same dates.  There be only two rows for E with end dates as 07/22/1992 and 08/02/1992 only.  The script needs some minor changes and I am not able to figure the ones that would give the desired output. Thanks!

Comment: What should be the value for var1 for E and F?

Comment: Thanks chinsoon.  The var1 and ranges are fine but the ranges should begin with pre and end with post for all IDs. So for ID E,since pre does not cover the entire range, we get additional row at row 9, and for id F, we get an additional row of 16.

Comment: Thanks Chinsoon for the edits!   Appreciate it very much.  I don't know how you can figure it out and do it so quickly!